# what is the difference between charlatan and chicanery?

Tags: vocabulary

I am skeptical abut the difference between the above two words. When I googled it shows charlatan is "a person falsely claiming to have a special knowledge or skill." and chicanary is "trickery, deception"..In my case both are same synonyms ...But it doesn't show in google.

Please provide precise meaning between these two...

Comment: You can find definitions for both words in any dictionary. Notice that a charlatan is a person, whereas chicanery a kind of behavior or activity. They are really very dissimilar words.

Answer (score 1):

A charlatan may use ***[chicanery](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chicanery);*** i. e., "actions or statements that trick people into believing something that is not true; deception or trickery," but they are not synonyms.

***"[Charlatan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charlatan)"***: a person who falsely pretends to know or be something in order to deceive people."

(Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I don't yet know how to do that.